# How can I set the same background to all UIViewController classes in PageViewController with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm creating a `PageViewController` and following this tutorial:

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/

Author creates an array with UIViewControllers by writing:

```
private(set) lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
    return [self.newColoredViewController("Green"),
        self.newColoredViewController("Red"),
        self.newColoredViewController("Blue")]
}()

private func newColoredViewController(color: String) -> UIViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) .
        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("\(color)ViewController")
}
```

I did a similar thing by writing:

```
private(set) lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
    return [self.newPagedViewController("TutorialViewController1"),
        self.newPagedViewController("TutorialViewController2"),
        self.newPagedViewController("TutorialViewController3"),
        self.newPagedViewController("TutorialViewController4"),
        self.newPagedViewController("TutorialViewController5")]
}()

private func newPagedViewController(name: String) -> UIViewController {

    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) .
        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("\(name)")
}
```

and it works, but it creates 5 controllers, each with white background.
How can I implement a feature that each created PageViewController has a background set by my custom code:

```
let background = CAGradientLayer().greenBlue()
    background.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(background, atIndex: 0)
```

?

I tried to put this code inside:

```
private func newPagedViewController(name: String) -> UIViewController {

 let background = CAGradientLayer().greenBlue()
    background.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(background, atIndex: 0)

    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) .
        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("\(name)")
}
```

but it didn't do the trick and the background stays white... How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the color of the instantiated View Controller:

```
private func newPagedViewController(name: String) -> UIViewController {

   let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) .
    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("\(name)")

   vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 25/255.0, green: 134/255.0, blue: 125/255.0, alpha: 1)


   return vc
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this line `vc.view.backgroundColor = CAGradientLayer().greenBlue()` throws an error `cannot assign value of type "CAGradientLayer" to type "UIColor?". Is there any way I could fix it?

Comment: I edited the post to show a UIColor similar to a greenish blue